# How to compute isometry group directly

Tags: symmetric-groups, isometry

> Let $M=\Bbb S^1 \times \Bbb R$ be the cylinder. I want to compute its isometry group *directly*. I know some (possibly all) of its elements:
>
> 1. reflection around line perpendicular to $\Bbb R$. by applying this reflection twice it satisfies $R^2=\rm id$.
> 2. rotations around central line and I think it is $\Bbb S^1$.
> 3. translations along central line and I think it is  $\Bbb R$.

What is the group generated by these elements? Is it $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb R\times \{I,-I\}$?

> Next case, consider $\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb  S^1$. For this one we have:
>
> 1. Rotations around central vertical line  and I think it is $\Bbb S^1$.
> 2. Rotations inward!! (maybe this one is also $\Bbb S^1$).
> 3. horizontal plane Reflections: $A^2=id$.
> 4. vertical plane Reflections: $B^2=id$.

So $\mathrm{Isom}(\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb  S^1)=\left<A, B, \Bbb S^1_1, \Bbb S^1_2 \ \big\vert\ A^2=B^2=id\right>=?$.

Comment: That's OK now? but they have same meaning. Isn't?

Comment: 1. The translations and reflections don't commute, it's rather a semidirect product. 2. It's not a clear presentation, also what are the relations?

Comment: I think $AB=BA$.